# Compiler Enabled on admin, Disabled on cli

Tags: compiler, compilation

My Magento's 1.9.2.1 Admin panel shows:

```
Compiler Status: Enabled
Compilation State: Compiled
Collected Files Count: 7947
Compiled Scopes Count: 4
```

If I click on Disable, it says that it's now Disabled but on Compiler Status I still get Enabled.

Now, when I go to CLI and enter:

```
[root@hostname httpdocs]# php -f shell/compiler.php -- state
```

I get:

```
Compiler Status:          Disabled
Compilation State:        Compiled
Collected Files Count:    7947
Compiled Scopes Count:    4
```

If I disable Compilation with compiler.php --disable my Admin panel still says "Enabled".

If I click on Run Compilation process on Admin I get Error 500 and I fix it through compiler.php

Is the above normal or what? Is my compiler Enabled or Disabled?

FYI, I use Zend OPCache on Centos 7 for what it matters.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have to manually flush the opcache in order PHP to load the fresh updated includes/config.php
The easiest way to flush the opcache via CLI is a PHP service restart.